# Triggering Enhanced Input Actions via inputs with modifier keys (Shift/Alt/Ctrl) in UE5

Tags: input, mouse, rts, keyboard, unreal-5

This question refers to the use of [enhanced input](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/enhanced-input-in-unreal-engine/) in Unreal Engine 5. Whenever I say "modifier", I refer to modifier keys such as Shift, Alt, and Ctrl (rather than the Input Modifers such as Dead Zone and Aim Assist).

I am trying to bind actions to mouse and keyboard inputs that require the user to hold a modifier key, e.g. the following ones, which one would typically find in RTS type games:

- `Left click without modifiers` to select a unit
- `Left click + Shift` to add to selection
- Keyboard key `1` to select the units in control group #1
- `1 + Ctrl` to define control group #1
- `1 + Shift` to add to control group #1

This can be easily achieved through the deprecated Action Mapping in the Project Settings:

[image: Deprecated action mapping]

However, I am **looking for a way to achieve the same through the preferred Enhanced Input Actions and Input Mapping Context**. How does that work?

I could probably achieve the desired outcome with a Chorded Action (by defining a helper action for "Shift is Down" and then adding it as Chord Action to the left click. However, not only would I need to do this with the modifier I want, I would even need to add Chord Actions for those *I don't want*: otherwise if shift is down, both "Left click+shift" and "Only left click" will fire.  That sounds insane. What am I missing (and why don't I find this in the docs -- this seems like a common use case)?

Comment: It seems the insane solution I outlined above is in fact the only known one: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/enhanced-input-key-with-modifier/486208/2. The question was asked again in Feb 2023 and still has no better solution: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/enhanced-input-key-with-modifier/763258

Answer (score 4):

After doing some more research and implementing a solution that does work for me, I feel confident to be able to answer my own question. Unfortunately, the answer is: It's as cumbersome as already outlined in the question.

- Create Input Actions for Shift, Alt, and Control, and a dedicated Input Mapping that maps the respective left and right keys to these Input Actions. No special Trigger is needed for that.

  [image: Mappings window screenshot]

  These platform specific actions actually defeat the purpose of the entire approach, but it gets the job done.
- Always have this Input Mapping added to the Enhanced Input Local Player Subsystem with a sufficiently high priority.
- Create a second input mapping that holds your actual actions. For each action that requires a modifier key, use a `Chorded Action`, and use the Input Actions created above as the `Chord Action`.

  [image: Input action with modifiers]
- Note that the question contains an unnecessary assumption: It is *not* necessary to enforce *absence* of a modifier key for the action that doesn't require one. For some reason, the more specific action (the one that does specify a Chorded Action) takes precedence over the general one, but I found no documentation about how this works precisely. This makes it a bit less cumbersome than suggested in the question.

An almost identical solution has been posted in the [UE Forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/enhanced-input-key-with-modifier/486208/2) and [repeated in February 2023](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/enhanced-input-key-with-modifier/763258), so there's likely no better solution possible at the moment. If a better option will be made available in a future version of Unreal Engine, please post another answer and I'll mark that one as correct.